# How to a prevent spoon from falling into soup?

Tags: soup, utensils

When preparing a soup, the spoon which I use to stir the soup with, often falls in. Is there any way to prevent the spoon from falling into the soup?

Comment: Hold it tight there!!!

Comment: Do you mean once you've finished stirring and you set the spoon aside, it falls in? Because the simple solution is to just take the spoon out of the pan completely...

Comment: Make your soup so thick the spoon won't move. Search the web for cement-based recipes, or make a triple-strength split pea soup. Another option is to cut a deep groove in the pan which will keep the spoon from sliding. Of course, you could also just use a longer spoon, but that's too simple!

Comment: They also make spoons that have a little hook on them (so they catch before falling in), and there are '[pot clips](http://www.amazon.com/Trudeau-BCRF-Mess-Utensil-Clip/dp/B000UF0OP6)' that attach to the pot w/out taking up space of a traditional spoon rest.  (I like the clips, but not all utensils work in it, so I still use a spoon rest, too.  A small plate also works.

Answer (score 8):

The obvious solution is to not let the spoon in the pot. While you may just let it rest on the pot, you can also use a spoon rest, as I do.

[Spoon rests](https://www.google.ca/search?q=spoon%20rest&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=933&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=ua82VL6BHM2iyATZ_IKIBw&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ)

I always let one of those on the oven so that I can avoid making a mess of my kitchen when I am finished using my ustensils.

Comment: +1 for spoon rests. This is the most practical, reliable answer.

Answer (score 7):

Use a longer spoon?  Stir, then set on spoon rack next to pan?

Answer (score 5):

A few ways exist to keep your spoon from falling into your soup. The first of which is to not keep your spoon in your soup. How to do that however, is quite varied:

1. Purchase a [spoon rest](https://www.google.com/search?q=spoon+rest&tbm=isch&biw=1920&bih=1019).
2. Use a clean and empty plate to rest your spoon on by laying the spoon head on the plate.

I, being a bit of a frugal cook, don't own a spoon rest. I use a plate - oftentimes the same plate where I used to arrange the mise en place veggies.